# The performance of Java/Scala's Deflator for compressing BitSet

Tags: java, scala, compression

I have this Scala code that uses Java's Deflator/Inflator.

```
  def compress(bytes: Array[Byte]): Array[Byte] = {
    val deflater = new java.util.zip.Deflater
    val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream
    val dos = new DeflaterOutputStream(baos, deflater)
    dos.write(bytes)
    baos.close
    dos.finish
    dos.close
    baos.toByteArray
  }

  def decompress(bytes: Array[Byte]): String /*Array[Byte]*/ = {
    val deflater = new java.util.zip.Inflater()
    val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(512)
    val bytesIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)
    val in = new InflaterInputStream(bytesIn, deflater)
    var go = true
    while (go) {
      val b = in.read
      if (b == -1)
        go = false
      else
        baos.write(b)
    }
    baos.close
    in.close
    // String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset)
    new String(baos.toByteArray, "ASCII")
  }
```

I need to compress BitSet that has only one bit (100th bit from 13 x 8 = 104 bits) set.

```
val bs = new util.BitSet()
bs.set(100)
val ba = bs.toByteArray
val z = gzip.compress(ba)
println(ba.size)
println(ba.mkString(":"))
println(z.size)
println(z.mkString(":"))
```

I expect some dramatic size reduction, but the result is that I save only one byte.

```
13
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:16
12
120:-100:99:96:64:0:1:0:0:29:0:17
```

Is this expected results for Java's Deflator? Is there any better compressor for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this expected results for Java's Deflator?

It is what I would expect.  The "deflate" compression algorithm is designed for compression of large files.  For a tiny file (13 bytes), the overheads in the encoding are likely to balance (or even exceed) the compression that is achieved.

> Is there any better compressor for this case?

I wouldn't expect any of the compression algorithms supported by the standard Java libraries to do much better.  If you want good performance on tiny bitmaps, you will probably need to design a custom compressor from first principles.

For example, a sparse bitmap can be represented as a sequence of numbers (in this case `byte` values) that denote the bits that have been set, or as a sequence of numbers that represent runs of consecutive ones or zeros.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is GZIP encoded data contains header information which takes up bytes.  This doesn't usually matter since the size of data to compress is usually much larger.

IF you have mostly zeros (or any runs of identical values) and a few bytes of something else, perhaps a run length encoding is better.

IF you really only have 1 bit set then you can come up with your own encoding that only encodes the offset of that single bit if the bitSet is fixed length.